# How can I get my image to float to the right of my div?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to get an image to float to the right of my div with a little space around the edges. I want the image to fill the majority of the div but with space for the link 'view project' beneath it. I've tried different floats, widths and even adjusted padding but still cannot get it to work. Can anyone tell me how to rectify this? Many thanks in advance. This is the page link if needed: http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/design.html

HTML:

```
<div id="middle">

    <div class="section group">
        <div class="block-1">
        <h2>Logo Redesign & Style Guide</h2>
        <p><h3>This brief involved...</h3></p>
        <div class="snapshot">
        <a href="portfolioresources/styleguide.pdf"><img src="portfolioresources/scenelogo.png"></a>
        <a href="portfolioresources/styleguide.pdf" target="_blank">View Project</a>

        </div></div>

        <div class="block-2">
        <h2>TV Idents</h2>
        <p>This brief involved...</p>
        <a href=".....pdf" target="_blank">View Project</a>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="section group">
    <div class="block-3">
        <h2>Web Banners</h2>
        <p>This brief involved...</p>
        <a href=".....pdf" target="_blank">View Project</a>
        </div>

    <div class="block-4">
        <h2>Multiformat Campaign</h2>
        <p>This brief involved...</p>
        <a href=".....pdf" target="_blank">View TV Idents</a>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for this particular bit (although inspect element might show other things that are affecting my divs):

```
    /* design page grids */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.colu {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.colu:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .colu { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}

/* style grids  */

#middle {
    width: 90%; 
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.block-1 {
    background-color:#ECECEC;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;

}

.block-2 {
    background-color: white;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-top: 2px solid #FADBC8;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FADBC8;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;

}

.block-3 {
    background-color:#ECECEC;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px
}


.block-4 {
    background-color: white;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-top: 2px solid #FADBC8;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FADBC8;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;

}

.block-1 img {
    height: 140px;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);    
}

.snapshot a {
    float: right;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-family: "Raleway";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DO this  in snapshot class

```
<div class="snapshot">
        <a href="portfolioresources/styleguide.pdf"><div class="wrap" ><img src="portfolioresources/scenelogo.png"></div></a>
        <a href="portfolioresources/styleguide.pdf" target="_blank">View Project</a>

        </div></div>
```

and  add this to ur css file to sortify your error

```
.wrap{
     padding:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While doing these kinda things on your own is definitely useful, so you can learn the ropes and inner workings first, be sure to use a css framework in the future (like bootstrap) so you can knock these out quickly.

```
<div class="view-project">

<img ... />

<span>View Project</span>

</div>
```

In your css:

```
.view-project{ float: right; width:300px; padding:40px; }
.view-project img,.view-project span{ display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion: if you want your image at the right of the div with view project beneath, I think you should contain them in another div. Like this:

```
   <div class="snapshot">
        <div>
            <a href="portfolioresources/styleguide.pdf"><img src="portfolioresources/scenelogo.png"></a>
            <a href="portfolioresources/styleguide.pdf" target="_blank">View Project</a>
    </div>
           </div>
```

Then float that div right and remove all other floats.

If you want the image on top of view project, set `display: block;` to your 'a' elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least define a width for snapshot. by making the width of snapshot equal the width of the image, this will leave no room for the link and will force it to drop below the image. Remove any floating on the image and link, and rather float snapshot to the right